# Increase parent div height when more child is added

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a parent div with multiple child divs. Currently, the child divs are spaced around the parent div in order to fit the parent div equally and it works fine but what I'm trying to achieve is when more child divs are added the parent divs height increases in size but the child divs height stays the same. How can I achieve this? What it currently does when you add more child divs is the parent height stays the same but the child divs height will get shorter in order to fit the parent div but what I want is the other way around. When more child div is added I want the parent div to increase in height kinda like the parent div having a height of auto. How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: gold;
}

.data {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: #187bcd;
  border-top: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="data">

  </div>
  <div class="data">

  </div>
  <div class="data">

  </div>
  <div class="data">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better in this use case to not use percentages

Comment: @mstephen19 why not? And should I use vh/px instead?

Comment: Use `vh` if you want the size to be relative to the viewport height. You can also use `px` if you want a fixed height, regardless of the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the % height from your .items div, then set a fixed height on your child elems.

```html
<button>Add div</button>
<div class="items">
    <div class="data"></div>
    <div class="data"></div>
</div>

<style>
    .items {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 6%;
        left: 15%;
        width: 70%;
        background-color: gold;
    }

    .data {
        width: 100%;
        height: 75px; /* Fixed height here */
        background-color: #187bcd;
        border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    }
</style>

<script>
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const div = document.querySelector('div.items');

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.className = 'data';
        div.appendChild(newDiv);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a non-parentally-relative length unit (like em and px) to do that, if that's what you want:

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: gold;
}

.data {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #187bcd;
  border-top: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="data">

  </div>
  <div class="data">

  </div>
  <div class="data">

  </div>
  <div class="data">

  </div>
    <div class="data">

  </div>
  <div class="data">

  </div>
  <div class="data">

  </div>
  <div class="data">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, this is what I want thanks I will accept the answer when It lets me in 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

min-height: (less than or equals the height of the child element)

Comment: " (less than or equals the height of the child element)" so use js to get the height and apply it is your suggestion?

Comment: Depends if the height of the child element is `dynamic` but if you already know the height of the child element just use it as the minimum height for the parent.

Comment: @seriously you don't need JS to do that, CSS has the calc() function baked in

Comment: @mstephen19 yeah but how can I use calc to get the height of the child element?